# How to install node.js and run js files using it?

Tags: php, linux, node.js

I have made a website that has some notification action done by socket.io which is written in server.js file. The server.js file is run on cmd using node.js. It working perfectly fine on my localhost(xampp server). Now I want to implement it on the live server which is linux. How do I proceed it. The server has been installed with node.js. How should i run the server.js file on it which should be ran all the time in the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: try this
node server.js